# Gridview last row being cut off

Tags: android, gridview

I am using a gridview to display a collection of items in the form of an image with a textview beneath them for their title.

The final item of collection of items is unique in the fact that it only has an image, no textview (this might be relevant).

At the moment I am finding that as soon as a row is created that has a normal item and an image only item in it, the textview is cutoff.

I have tried setting the min height and height of the items but it doesn't seem to affect the grid at all.

Grid:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/Background"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <GridView
    android:id="@+id/connection_grid"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="25dip"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="25dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Grid Item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/screencap_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/RowBorderBackground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/connection_icon"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="147dip"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_view_selector"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/devicetype_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/RowBorderBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="-2dip"
        android:padding="2dip">
        <TextView
            android:text="NA"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/device_type" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connection_name"
        android:text="Machine 1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set some **paddingBottom** to gridview gridview class.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/Background"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridView
android:id="@+id/connection_grid"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:horizontalSpacing="25dip"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="25dip"
android:paddingBottom="20dip"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've already tried that unfortunately and it doesn't help the issue.

Comment: Why do you use Relative Layout when you have linear layout?

Comment: Now try to remove margin from relativelayout of gridview item and give paddingBotom to that textview

Comment: Thanks, but the textview is still cut off even with padding.

Comment: Give me the actual view, what you want